# How can I send data to a PHP script from a dynamically generated page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, tcpdf

I'm trying to dynamically create a PDF using the [TCPDF library](http://www.tcpdf.org) in a document very much like [this one](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.phps). The output of the PDF is HTML, which I can represent with a string in a variable, as in the example above:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<html>bar</html>
EOD;
```

The content I want is Wordpress post metadata which I call within the theme using the [More Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) plugin like so:

```
<?php more_fields('foo','','',1); ?>
```

...which outputs some HTML which I've specified in the plugin settings. Unless I'm wrong, I can't make that call again directly from my PDF-generating script without authoring my own plugin. So how can I use JS to send the HTML to the script from a clickable "View PDF" link? Mind you, it's a full page of text, not just a few characters, if that matters.

Comment: try render the page html in server context and then generate the pdf using the rendered html page. just an idea because i'm not know exactly how to do this using wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden Forms?

```
<form method="post" action="la.php"><input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"></form>
```